# Parsing Data from in Python using xml airnow.gov

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm new to python and xml. I'm trying to get air quality index data from the airnow.gov website. I am using Inductive Automation's Ignition software to display this information. When I did this for weather, the government site I used had their data in an easy to parse format.

This one isn't so simple though. My output contains everything up to the second description element, which contains the only data I really need - Air Quality Index. It's like it's skipping the remaining data.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

My Code:

```
import system
import xml.dom.minidom

url = "http://feeds.enviroflash.info/rss/realtime/133.xml"

response = system.net.httpGet(url)

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(response)

for tag in dom.getElementsByTagName("*"):
print tag.firstChild.data
```

DATA:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>San Francisco, CA - Current Air Quality</title>
<link>http://www.airnow.gov/</link>
<description>EnviroFlash RSS Feed</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<webMaster>
airnowdmc@sonomatech.com (AIRNow Data Management Center)
</webMaster>
<pubDate>Thu, 12 Oct 2017 08:45:10 PDT</pubDate>
<item>
<title>San Francisco, CA - Current Air Quality</title>
<link>
http://feeds.enviroflash.info/rss/realtime/133.xml?id=AC9AF12B-02F4-5A9E-BD504999C6EF606E
</link>
<description>
<!--  Format data output  -->
 <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <table style="width: 350px;">    
 <tr> <td> <br> </td> </tr> <tr> <td valign="top">
 <div><b>Location:</b> San Francisco, CA</div><br /> <div> <b>Current
 Air Quality:</b> 10/12/17 8:00 AM PDT<br /><br /> <div> Unhealthy -
 156 AQI - Particle Pollution (2.5 microns)<br /> <br /> Good - 1 AQI -
 Ozone<br /> <br /> </div> </div> <div><b>Agency:</b> San Francisco Bay
 Area AQMD </div><br /> <div><i>Last Update: Thu, 12 Oct 2017 08:45:10
 PDT</i></div> </td> </tr> </table> </div>
</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

My OUTPUT:

```
San Francisco, CA - Current Air Quality
http://www.airnow.gov/
EnviroFlash RSS Feed
en-us
airnowdmc@sonomatech.com (AIRNow Data Management Center)
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 08:45:10 PDT


San Francisco, CA - Current Air Quality
http://feeds.enviroflash.info/rss/realtime/133.xml?id=AC9AF12B-02F4-5A9E-BD504999C6EF606E
```

Comment: The first child node of `description` is the comment. You want the 2nd child. Example: `tag = dom.getElementsByTagName("description")[1]
print(tag.childNodes[2].data)`

Answer (score 0):

First HTML is not XML. So please consider using BeautifulSoup to do just the same and in a similar manner. As an example `<br>` is a valid tag without any matching closing tag in html. But an xml parser will throw an error.

That said see below:-

```
#Will give you all text in the html, your codes attempt
for tag in dom.getElementsByTagName("*"):
    if tag.firstChild and not isinstance(tag.firstChild,xml.dom.minidom.Element) :
        if(len(tag.firstChild.data.strip())>0):
            print tag.firstChild.wholeText
print('\n\n\n')
#Will give you text from just the second description.
#I believe all parts here are important like time/place/last-update etc..
desc=dom.getElementsByTagName("description")[1]
for tag in desc.getElementsByTagName("*"):
    for node in tag.childNodes:
        if( isinstance(node,xml.dom.minidom.Text) and len(node.data.strip())>0):
            print node.data
```

Hope you can figure out how to get `Location: San Francisco, CA` instead of `San Francisco, CA Location:`